# Git push gives Error reading command stream

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to push my project to github repository. On my new project I did following commands:

```
git init
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myaccount/MyRepoName.git
```

But when I'm trying to push my commit like this:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It gives me following error information:

```
fatal: Full write to remote helper failed: Invalid argument
Error reading command stream
```

I found nothing about this in google. Please, help me fix this issue.

Comment: Use the ssh read/write URL instead of using the read-only https url. it should be like git@github.com/myaccount/MyRepoName.git.

Comment: Now it gives me message:
fatal: 'git@github.com/myaccount/MyRepoName.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be, 
git@github.com:username/Repo.git

Comment: OK, It looks it fix that issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message comes from [transport-helper.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/transport-helper.c#L80-L86), which calls one of the [git remote helpers](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers).

It is possible, after the [recent DDoS](https://status.github.com/messages) that GitHub had to endure, that not all repos support well https push, hence the suggestion to switch transport protocol (with ssh `git@github.com:username/repo.git`, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188396/git-push-gives-error-reading-command-stream#comment28391349_19188396) by [gnuanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230782/gnuanu)).

But you should check in a few days if https works again for your repo.

Comment: Yes, as I said in answer gnuanu, it works for me :) Thank you!